# setTimeout using Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I have this:

```
  private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  executor.execute(() -> {
     Thread.sleep(100);
      doSomething();
  });
```

since I am reusing a thread, I am blocking it if others want to use the thread. My question is - is there a way to simply register a callback, something like this:

```
   executor.execute(() -> {
        timers.setTimeout(() -> {  // imaginary utility
             doSomething();
        },100);
   });
```

is this possible with core Java?

Comment: I think you want [`CompletableFuture`s](http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html)

Comment: I wonder if there is any relationship between CompletableFuture and the Future class in vertx

Comment: It’s unlikely - while Vert.x uses the JVM as a runtime environment, it doesn’t appear to borrow any of Java’s runtime libraries

Comment: @MTCoster yeah my primary fear is that CompletableFutures that don't access an event loop are just using Thread.sleep under the hood or something

Comment: Why does it matter whether it uses `Thread.sleep()`? The call to `execute()` returns immediately, so your main thread will continue to be responsive

Comment: You're right about the main thread, but overlooking how the thread in the threadpool suffers. There's only one thread in the threadpool, it gets reused, so Thread.sleep is blocking and doing nothing productive in the process. Thread.sleep is pretty much the last thing you want to call, whether you are doing synchronous or asynchronous servers, either way it's bad. That's because a thread takes up a lot of resources by nature.

Comment: Important: you wanna kill thread or make it sleep after timeout??

Comment: @CommonMan I don't understand the question, sorry. I want to reuse the thread, hence the threadpool, but I don't want to block the thread unnecessarily - i just want to make sure the callback is asynchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it looks like this works fine, I tested it on Java 10:

```
CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).execute(() -> {
    doSomething();
});
```